# UML specification, understanding code

Tags: uml

I was reading the UML specification (http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/PDF) and I found here an there some "code" of this type:

```
body: if alias->notEmpty() then
 alias
else
 importedElement.name
endif
```

for example at page 87. Where I can find the specification for this language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is OCL.

You can download the spec from here: http://www.omg.org/spec/OCL/2.3.1/PDF/